# Amplify configuration related issues in Flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, configuration, aws-amplify

I have created an app with AWS Amplify as backend and I have initialized all the plugins and configured the app programmatically. But it's not until just now that I've run it and it ain't configuring. It's been minutes I've been waiting for it. Here's how my code looks like please help me find any bugs.

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print

import 'package:amplify_analytics_pinpoint/amplify_analytics_pinpoint.dart';
import 'package:amplify_api/amplify_api.dart';
import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
import 'package:amplify_datastore/amplify_datastore.dart';
import 'package:amplify_datastore/amplify_datastore_stream_controller.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:amplify_storage_s3/amplify_storage_s3.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:tweet/amplifyconfiguration.dart';
import 'package:tweet/auth/auth.dart';
import 'package:tweet/provider/user_provider.dart';

class EntryPoint extends StatefulWidget {
  const EntryPoint({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EntryPoint> createState() => _EntryPointState();
}

bool isConfigured = false;

class _EntryPointState extends State<EntryPoint> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _amplifyConfig();
    _addData();
  }

  void _amplifyConfig() async {
    try {
      await Amplify.addPlugins(
        [
          AmplifyAPI(),
          AmplifyAnalyticsPinpoint(),
          AmplifyAuthCognito(),
          AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: modelProvider),
          AmplifyStorageS3(),
        ],
      );
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);

      setState(() {
        isConfigured = true;
      });
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  _addData() async {
    UserProvider _userProvider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
    await _userProvider.refreshUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: isConfigured
          ? const AuthSetUp()
          : const CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate your help fam. Thank you

Comment: Did you see any error in the logs? Either at build step or when you perform any aws operation e.g. calling API,s3, etc.?
Attaching full console output might also help.

Comment: I found this error message ~ E /flutter ( 8605): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: AmplifyException(message: Auth plugin has not been added to Amplify, recoverySuggestion: Add Auth plugin to Amplify and call configure before calling Auth related APIs, underlyingException: null)

Comment: Are you sure you correctly added auth? Run ```amplify add auth``` or ```amplify update auth``` in your project root folder. Make sure you follow all the setup: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#prerequisites

Comment: I am sure and now actually I deleted the _addData function and auth is suddenly configured and I'm getting at different error messages on DataStore modelProviders not being configured